# How to overcome caching issues when combining api calls with Selenium UI tests

Tags: c#, rest, api, selenium, caching

I've started to run into caching problems with the application I'm writing tests for and at the moment I can't see a clean solution. I'm hoping someone might be able to offer some pointers.

Some of my tests require a fair amount of test data setup before the actual UI test can be executed. To ensure the tests are atomic and can be executed in parallel, the setup data required for each test is created before the UI test is run. This is typically done via a sequence of api calls. To create this data via the UI could take upwards of 5-10 minutes. Only after all api calls have returned 200 O.K will the browser open and the 'actual' UI test start.

This approach had been working well for me until I started to notice caching issues. By that I mean data I created via the api was often not available when the UI test needed to interact with it (e.g. in a dropdown). Only after a few F5 refreshes would the data appear.

Because there is no way to 'poll' the data to confirm its existence in a dropdown, the only hacky solution is keep pressing F5 until it appears. It's not clean at all though as a refresh will remove any data you have added up to that point, and if it's a single page application, may navigate you to a different tab from where you were.

Is there anything either me or the developers can do to solve this particular problem?

Many thanks,

Comment: If you open the UI and a dropdown is empty when it should be populated with data from an API, then you have a problem with the API.  Not sure why you're looking at this with a "fix it so we can test" way of thinking.  It looks to me that testing has found a bug - job done!  Tell the devs to fix it.

Comment: Hi Archer. This issue is a real bone of contention as no 'human' user would perform the sequence of actions and at the speed that my automation does to recreate the issue. My view was that if active data exists in the database or you've had a successful api response before your application is opened, ALL the active data should be available in the application. Aside from the concept of server side caching, I don't know enough about the application to understand why this might not/can not be possible.

Comment: @Konzy262 What happens if you restart IIS after all the api calls have been made? does that solve the problem?

Comment: I agree with you.  I'd suggest showing one of the developers what happens.  I can't imagine a tester showing that to me and me just shrugging it off.  I'd *have* to fix it!  In my mind, though, if you have to do anything at all to make a test pass then it's failed.  If your developers don't see that then there's not much you can do. (kill them all)

Comment: @MoeGhafari I've not tried this and it's an interesting chain of thought, however although it's a test environment I would be worried about disruption to other testers. Our automation databases are seperate but the test site is shared.

Comment: @Konzy262 How about disable caching in IIS for your site? This way you wont have to restart it, nonetheless this is still a speculation, need to verify that disabling the cache will resolve your issue.